# Computer vision and body composition

Tags: api, computer-vision, computer-science, detection

We have program that detect objects in images. 
Are there some API that detect body comosition of people in image?
We need to classify like "fat", "thin", "tall", "short", etc

Answer (score 0):

I think so there are some APIs for Java using Kinnect but if you are studying a computer science degree I recommend you to understand and replicate an existing alghorithm. You can start by reading some articles like [this](https://www.cs.umd.edu/sites/default/files/scholarly_papers/neetiPaper_1.pdf%20).

Comment: No. It is not for my study degree, but for work project. We need to classify like "fat", "thin", "tall", "short", etc. Thanks for you advices!

Comment: Ohh, it is not a very complex problem, [this](http://www.ra-ma.es/libros/VISION-ARTIFICIAL-RASGOS-DESCRIPTORES-PARA-EL-RECONOCIMIENTO-DE-OBJETOS/80937/978-84-9964-142-3) book can help you.